# How to count without duplicates in two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, count

I have table:

```
+----------------+
| table          |
+----------------+
| u_id | sail_id |
+----------------+
| 1    | 5       |
| 1    | 5       |
| 2    | 5       |
| 2    | 4       |
| 1    | 4       |
+----------------+
```

How to write sql statement to count different `u_id` with different `sail_id` (means no duplicate)?

Example:
if `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY sail_id`, result will be `2`

if `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY sail_id, user_id`, result will be `1`

I need result to be `4` (because there are 5 rows and only first and second rows have same u_id and sail_id).
Maybe I need add somewhere `DISTINCT`.

Comment: You have no Primary Key. Further down the road, this may prove problematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u_id,sail_id)
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3f50b/6/0)**</kbd>

2) You can use subquery with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT u_id, sail_id
      FROM table) AS sub;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400762)**</kbd>

3) You can use subquery with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT u_id, sail_id
      FROM table
      GROUP BY u_id, sail_id) AS sub;
```

4) Last possibility is to use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(u_id,',',sail_id))
FROM table;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3f50b/5/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @Strawberry Hahahha, you are absolutely right.  I am SQL Server oriented and there  this syntax is not supported